# Is my DSL modem attempting a man-in-the-middle?

Tags: ssl

Starting about 2 months ago, when using my laptop at home, I will occasionally get application errors about an invalid or untrusted certificate. When I click the button to get details on the certificate in question, I get a windows "Verify Certificate" dialog with this information:

"This CA Root certificate is not trusted. To enable trust, install this certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. Issued to: C1100T Issued By: C1100T Valid from 5/24/2016 to 5/24/2031"

Needless to say, I have not installed this cert in my root store.

The Technicolor C1100T is the DSL modem issued by my ISP. Why am I getting a certificate from my DSL modem when, for example, using Google Hangouts or browsing an HTTPS website?

Comment: Since this is your ISP's modem, I would contact their support and ask them to update it. This is their responsibility - not yours.

Comment: "Why am I getting a certificate from my DSL modem when, for example, using Google Hangouts or browsing an HTTPS website?" - One of the few legitmant reasons, a certificate like this would be required, is if the configuration page for the device was being delevered over a secure encrypted HTTP connection